# Get usb device tree in kernel module

Tags: linux-device-driver

For some reason, I need whether two specified usb devices are connected to the same hub on the specified port.

For example device A is connected on port 1 of hub and device B is connected on port 3 of hub, I want to check this combination when device A and device B are enumerated. Then drive device A and device B in a special way, and the devices that don't satisfy it are driven in the default way.

Now I can get the information of the connected hub through usb_device->parent, but how to get the information of the devices on the other ports of the hub?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the kernel? In user space you quite likely can achieve this with `libusb`.

Comment: Because I want to modify the flow of the kernel driver module to initialize the hardware, I don't know how to pass some parameters from user space to the kernel driver module to allow the driver to configure the hardware in a special way.

Comment: You write your own module for the same hardware and blacklist the original one. That's the standard way of overwriting modules.